# Best practice for Inline if statement in for loop

Tags: c#, .net

I want to copy Listbox items to StringCollection.
If the listbox items contains empty string then ignore

Why can i do this:

```
foreach (string item in lstModelUsers.Items)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item))
        continue;
    else
        Options.Default.ModelRemoveUsers.Add(item);
}
```

BUT not this:

```
foreach (string item in lstModelUsers.Items)
    string.IsNullOrEmpty(item)
        ? continue
        : Options.Default.ModelRemoveUsers.Add(item);
```

Although both appear equal, the inline `if` statement generates a syntax error.
What is the best practice?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do this?  Why does everyone want to do inline code, it is horrible, and it serves no purpose.

Comment: Some companies has their own coding guidlines, they recommend inline code, i think one of the benefits is to reduce amount of codes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't use the [conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) like that. It only accepts *expressions* as its operands. Your code fails to compile because [`continue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/923ahwt1%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) can only be used as a *statement*, not an expression.

A better approach is to negate the `if` expression so that you don't need the `continue`:

```
foreach (string item in lstModelUsers.Items)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item))
    { 
        Options.Default.ModelRemoveUsers.Add(item);              
    }
}
```

You could also use `Where`:

```
var itemsToAdd = lstModelUsers.Items
    .Cast<string>()
    .Where(item => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(item));

foreach (string item in itemsToAdd)
{
    Options.Default.ModelRemoveUsers.Add(item);   
}
```

If you are lucky, you may even find that `ModelRemoveUsers` has an `AddRange` method, then you don't need the loop at all:

```
var itemsToAdd = lstModelUsers.Items
    .Cast<string>()
    .Where(item => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(item));

Options.Default.ModelRemoveUsers.AddRange(itemsToAdd);
```

Comment: lstModelUsers is a ListBox.
I cannot use lstModelUsers.Items.Where ? do i have to Cast first or am i missing something?

Comment: @Maro: Yes, if it's the old WinForms ListBox, it does't use generics. You need to add a call to `Cast`. I've updated my answer to show how to do that.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use LINQ:

```
foreach (string item in lstModelUsers.Items.Where(user => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(user))
{
    Options.Default.ModelRemoveUsers.Add(item);
}
```

And depending on the type of `ModelRemoveUsers` you could make it into a single line

```
Options.Default.ModelRemoveUsers.AddRange(
    lstModelUsers.Items.Where(user => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(user));
```

But I prefer Mark Byers non-single line version as it is more readable and thus will be easier to maintain over time.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `continue` within the conditional operator.

The two "branches" of the conditional operator need to return the same type or types that can be implicitly converted to each other.

Answer (score 2):

No, they are not equal. The conditional operator (`? :`) requires the two result parts to end up in a value (`continue` doesn't have a value). Plus both values need to be of a similar type.